# I keep getting an error while using youtube v3 api with RAPIDAPI

Tags: reactjs, youtube-api, rapidapi

I was using the javascript mastery API course on youtube to try and create a youtube clone, but while trying to fetch videos using the api i got somer errors and the react app stopped rerenderng. The error occured after i put in this exact line `{item.id.videoId && <VideoCard video={item}/>}`

Here's my code for the video component

```
import {Stack, Box} from '@mui/material';
import {ChannelCard, VideoCard} from './';

const Videos = ({videos}) => {

  return (
    <Stack direction="row" flexWrap="wrap" justifyContent="start" gap={2}  >
        {videos.map((item, idx) => (
            <Box key={idx}>
                {item.id.videoId && <VideoCard video={item}/>}
            </Box>
            
        ))}
    </Stack>
  )
}

export default Videos
```

Here's the error

```
Videos.jsx:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'videoId')
    at Videos.jsx:9:1
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Videos (Videos.jsx:7:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably is because the `videoId` is on this path:

```
item.snippet.videoId
```

Response - extracted from the ["Example responses"](https://rapidapi.com/ytdlfree/api/youtube-v31?utm_source=youtube.com%2FJavaScriptMastery) tab.

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#captionListResponse",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#caption",
      "id": "AUieDaZHR-hdtpvJvd_dtt6cuYWaFGFlDocKBzLyQktj",
      "snippet": {
        "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10",
        "lastUpdated": "2013-11-14T08:09:57.310379Z",
        "trackKind": "standard",
        "language": "bg",
        "name": "",
        "audioTrackType": "unknown",
        "isCC": false,
        "isLarge": false,
        "isEasyReader": false,
        "isDraft": false,
        "isAutoSynced": false,
        "status": "serving"
      }
    },
    [...]
  ]
}
```

Comment: So what do I do now? Do I change item.id.videoId to item.snippet.videoId? Do you think that would fix it?

Comment: @FimberElems yes, please, change the code as you mentioned and try again.

Comment: I keep getting the same error